# Website access only with ip

Tags: dns, dhcp

I recently installed Linaro Ubuntu 12.04 on my cubie development board and I can access websites only with ip adresses, for example I can access google with 74.125.224.72.

I also can ping only ip adresses. My DNS adresses are set to google DNS 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in router settings. On Ubuntu I have set to ignore IPv6 and IPv4 to Automatic (DHCP) addresses only and specified google DNS there also.

My /etc/resolv.conf and hosts files are empty. Maybe this is a problem? Waiting for your help.

---

`EDIT:`
I found a solution. I just added these lines to my /etc/resolv.conf file:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.254 
nameserver 208.67.222.222 
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

First ip is my router's address and last two are opendns ip addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Try editing your resolv.conf and put

nameserver 8.8.8.8

Save it and give it a try, it should resolve correctly, its not a fix but a workaround.

Comment: They are using Network Manager to manage their DNS, and this is already one of the DNS servers they use.